# SQL Merge colums into one from diffe

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a typical users table where users are registered by first and last name
I also have a tournament registrations table where I keep the ids of users that are registered in a specific tournament. This table however has also a player1_text field where I keep the name of unregistered players participating to the tournamen.

What I want to do is run a query that I get all registered and unregistered players of a tournament into one column and sort them based on their name.
I run the following sql but get an empty result on the merged column

```
select tournaments_registrations.id
, player1_text
, users.fname
, users.sname
, concat(player1_text + users.sname + users.fname)  as merged   
from tournaments_registrations 
left join users 
  on tournaments_registrations.player1_id = users.id 
where tournament_id='10'
```

[Tournament Registrations table][image: 1]

[Users Table]

[image: 2]

[Sql Result][image: 3]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result of something unknown (NULL)  with anything is still unknown.

```
select tournaments_registrations.id
    , player1_text
    , users.fname
    , users.sname
    , concat(ifnull(player1_text,'') , ifnull(users.sname,'') , ifnull(users.fname,''))  as merged   
    from tournaments_registrations 
    left join users 
      on tournaments_registrations.player1_id = users.id 
    where tournament_id='10'
```

Comment: eshirvana thank you for your reply.
Running this sql statement produces the error "Incorrect parameter count in the call of native function 'isnull'

Comment: @KostasSpanos my bad , though its MSSQL , `IFNULL' function is the right one for MYSQL , ISNULL is for MSSQL

Comment: Now it works like a charm... Thank you very much eshirvana!!!!

Comment: See CONCAT_WS()

Answer (score 0):

I think you want either:

```
concat_ws(' ', player1_text, fname, sname) as merged
```

or:

```
coalesce(player1_text, concat_ws(' ', fname, sname)) as merged
```

I doubt you want the names to run together.